# Load a drawable from a resource

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a resource file with the xml definition of a shape which I want to use as a common background for various views..

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

How do I load this resource at runtime?
I tried to access R.drawable.resource_file_name but this is not recognized (the resource file name does not appear in R.java).

How do I load this resource?

Comment: Have you refreshed the `Project Explorer` window (Eclips) after adding the file..?

Comment: I can't provide an answer as I'm not on my dev machine. I have had this problem before though. For some reason <shape> is not classed as a drawable resource from what I remember. I seem to remember it may have to be embedded into another xml file. This may put you on the right path. If nobody responds I will try to get back later.

Comment: No problem. Just put the XML file in any of drawable folder, and then refresh or clean the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you put your xml file? I have code like this and it works just fine.

After checking that the file is in the drawable dir, try - if you're using eclipse - cleaning the project. I have to do this also from time to time. I don't know why but sometimes the code gets mangled up and views can't be found and runtime and such jokes. Cleaning the project in eclipse helped if something like that happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the resource name (preferred to be PNG or JPEG) to be only charachters in lower case as Android is picky for naming of resources (special chars not allowed) in Drawable directory.